# Error In to DataTable Insertion in to HTML- Dash

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I trying to inset a DataTable in my dashboard before my charts, but I always get an error related with a data table.

My Code is:

````
import dash_table_experiments
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import dash_table_experiments as dash_table
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import pandas as pd


html.Div(

dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns],
    data=df2.to_dict('records'),
),

)


app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children = "Dashboard Para Gestão De Produção",
    style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),
        html.Div(children = "_______________________________",
                 style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),


    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'lines-chart',
        figure = {
            'data' : [
        {'x': df2['OrderType'], 'y': df2['Qty'],                'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Dropado'},
        {'x': df2['OrderType'], 'y': df2['OrderTypeProcessed'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Realizado'}


            ],
            'layout' : {
                'title': 'Grafico'
            }
        }
    ),

])```
````

The error:

> TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument `data` Allowed arguments:
>   column_widths, columns, editable, enable_drag_and_drop, filterable,
>   filters, header_row_height, id, max_rows_in_viewport, min_height,
>   min_width, resizable, row_height, row_scroll_timeout, row_selectable,
>   row_update, rows, selected_row_indices, sortColumn, sortDirection,
>   sortable, tab_index

How can fix this error?